# Finding gcc4 while installing the NS2

Tags: ns2

I'm trying to install `NS2` (Network Simulator) in my system (windows 8.1 X64). After installing `Cygwin (6.3 X64)`, I install most packages that needed for NS2 but when I want to install `ns-allinone-2.35` the messages come up and say that I should install `gcc4`, `gcc4-g++` and `w32api`. It took me a whole day to find the packages and googling but I couldn't find these packages.
I would appreciate if give the reason and how can I install NS2.
I've bring the packages that I installed in the picture

[image]

Thanks